# Llamar Funciones de una clase desde una clase diferente?

Tags: javascript, ionic, typescript

Hace poco implemente una Liberia de javascript a mi proyecto en ionic ( winwheel.js)

tengo en mi Home.ts  la siguiente funcion

Exactament en esta linea de codigo `'callbackFinished' : this.alertPrize`  llamo a la funcion `alertPrize()`

Editado para mostrar todo el codigo

```html
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
//librerias
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';


//providers
import { PrimeraAperturaProvider } from '../../providers/primera-apertura/primera-apertura';

//pagnias
import { RuletaPage } from '../ruleta/ruleta';
import { GanadorPage } from '../ganador/ganador';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  public theWheel ;
  public DietaSeleccionada:any;
  public ListaComidas:any;
  public Imagen:any;
  public keys:any;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private storage: Storage,public _primera : PrimeraAperturaProvider,public modalCtrl: ModalController) {

  }

  ionViewDidLoad(){
    this.checkdata()
  }


  CrearRuleta(lista){
     let arr =[];
     arr = lista;
     let cantidad = arr.length
     
    
      this.theWheel = new Winwheel  
        ({
          'numSegments'  : cantidad,         // Cantidad de segmentos
          'outerRadius'  : 130,       // Tamaño de la ruleta
          'innerRadius'     : 10,             // Circulo del centro
          'textFontSize' : 14,        // Tamaño de la letra
          'segments'     : lista,      
          'animation' :               // Animacion
          {
              'type'     : 'spinToStop',
              'duration' : 5,
              'spins'    : 8,
              'callbackFinished' : this.alertPrize
          },
          'pins' :    // Specify pin parameters.
          {
              'number'      : 18,
              'outerRadius' : 5,
              'margin'      : 10,
              'fillStyle'   : '#FFF',
              'strokeStyle' : '#bfa100'
          }

      });
  }



   alertPrize(indicatedSegment) 
  {
    this.MostrarGanador(indicatedSegment)
 
  }

  MostrarGanador(dato){
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(GanadorPage)
    modal.onDidDismiss(data => { 

      console.log(dato)

    });
    modal.present();
  }


 

}
```

> core.js:1449 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'MostrarGanador' of
>   undefined
>       at webpackJsonp.292.HomePage.alertPrize (home.ts:74)
>       at f.winwheelStopAnimation (winwheel.min.js:53)
>       at f.i._callback (TweenMax.min.js:16)
>       at f.k.render (TweenMax.min.js:14)
>       at Object.i.render (TweenMax.min.js:17)
>       at Object.E._updateRoot.H.render (TweenMax.min.js:17)
>       at Object.i.dispatchEvent (TweenMax.min.js:16)
>       at s (TweenMax.min.js:16)
>       at t.invokeTask (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4751)

Creo que la funcion `MostrarGanador()` la toma como si fuera de otra clase  no se estoy confundido en este tema

Comment: Si el alertprize pertenece a otra clase asegurate de que esta este bien inicialidaza

Comment: Hola  alertPrize la tengo definida en home.ts

Comment: Suena a pérdida de contexto, ¿podrías poner el código en una sola pieza, en lugar de en trozos? No se ve donde están definidas las funciones, si son parte de una clase o no

Comment: Editado para mostrar todo el codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es la clásica pérdida de contexto de Javascript:

```js
class Ejemplo {

  constructor() {
    this.dato = 'Un dato';
  }
  
  escribeDato() {
    console.log(this.dato);
  }
}


let ej = new Ejemplo();
ej.escribeDato(); //funciona porque this es ej

function callback(func) {
  func();
}

callback(ej.escribeDato); //this es undefined
```

La solución es sencilla: la línea de código

```
'callbackFinished' : this.alertPrize
```

debería ser modificada a

```
'callbackFinished' : this.alertPrize.bind(this);
```

donde el método [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) de la clase `Function` *fija* el contexto (`this`) al parámetro que le pases.